# border-radius not being applied to React Component with nested Sass

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to make the `instagram-profile-picture` into a circle using `border-radius: 50%`. I do not see my changes working with my current `Sass` and I'm not sure why. I checked my inspector and the class is accurate. I tried taking the Sass out of the the nested Sass (`instagram-profile-picture` by itself) and that seemed to work but I'm wondering why `border-radius` isn't working when it is nested and all I see is a square.

Sass:

```
.instagram-cell-container {
    .instagram-text {
        padding: 20px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        .instagram-username {
            .instagram-profile-picture {
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        }
        .instagram-caption {

        }
        .instagram-likes {

        }
    }
}
```

React component:

```
class InstagramCell extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="instagram-cell-container">
                <div className="instagram-img">
                    <a href={ this.props.link }>
                        <img src={ this.props.image } />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="instragram-text">
                    <div className="instagram-username">
                        <a href={ this.props.link }>
                            <img src={ this.props.profile_picture } className="instagram-profile-picture" alt={ this.props.username }/>
                        </a>
                        <a href={ this.props.link }>
                            { this.props.username }
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="instragram-likes">
                        <p>{ this.props.likes }</p>
                        {/*<img src={} alt="likes"/>*/}
                    </div>
                    <div className="instragram-caption">
                        <p>
                            { this.props.caption }
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Applying those properties to an image won't work, you should apply them to the parent container.

```
.instagram-cell-container {
    .instagram-text {
        padding: 20px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        .instagram-username {
            a {
                display: block;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        }
        .instagram-caption {

        }
        .instagram-likes {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 2 `a` tags within `instagram-username` class. It will apply the styling to both? Also I tried your changes and they did not work =[

Comment: Give it a class, or use a selector to only target that first a tag. Also your class names have been spelt wrong.